# File Download not working in IE8 asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, download

I use the below code to push files to client from my asp.net web application.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/html";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.BinaryWrite(PdfBytes);
Response.End();
```

This is working fine in IE9. But on IE8 this is giving me "Internet explorer cannot download file. Internet explorer was not able to open the Internet Site."

IE8 is my org standard. Also I cant ask the client to change his settings.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you IE browser settings and then try.

```
Go to IE- Tools-> Internet Options.

Select Internet Zone. Click Custom Level.

In Downloads Section. Enable Automatic prompting for downloads
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that client level IE changes would solve this. But i cannot ask the large user base to change settings in their browers. hence need a code fix.